# How to separate the construction in its presentation in builder pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have this program that I think it represents a builder pattern, but I have this concern that I don't understand the separate construction in its representation from the GofF.

And here is the codes,

```
public class IDMaker {
public static void main(String[] args) {
   ...
    IDDirector director = new IDDirector();
    IDBuilder idB;
    switch(role){
        case 'a': {
                    idB = new StudentIDBuilder(idnumber, fname, lname);
                    break;
                }
        case 'b': {
                    idB = new FacultyIDBuilder(idnumber, fname, lname);
                    break;
                }
        default: {
                    idB = new StudentIDBuilder(idnumber, fname, lname);
                    break;
                }
    }
    director.MakeID(idB);
    ID id = idB.getID();
    ...
  }
}
```

This is the Director class of the program.

```
public class IDDirector {
public void MakeID(IDBuilder idB){
    idB.addIDNumber();
    idB.addName();
    idB.addWidth();
    idB.addHeight();
}
 }
```

This is the abstract builder of the program.

```
abstract class IDBuilder{
    public abstract void addIDNumber();
    public abstract void addName();
    public abstract void addWidth();
    public abstract void addHeight();
    public abstract ID getID();
}
```

This is the one of the concrete builder of the program.

```
class StudentIDBuilder extends IDBuilder{
    String idnumber;
    String fname;
    String lname;
    int width = 180;
    int height = 300;
    StudentIDBuilder(String idnumber, String fname,String lname){
        this.idnumber=idnumber;
        this.fname=fname;
        this.lname=lname;
    }

    private ID id = new ID();
    public void addIDNumber(){id.idnumber = this.idnumber;}
    public void addName(){id.fname = this.fname;id.lname = this.lname;}
    public void addWidth(){id.width = this.width;}
    public void addHeight(){id.height = this.height;}
    public ID getID(){return id;}
}
```

And this is the product of the program.

```
class ID{
    public String idnumber;
    public String fname;
    public String lname;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public String getIDNumber(){return this.idnumber;}
    public String getName(){return this.lname + ", " + fname;}
    public String getSize(){return width + "x" + height;}
}
```

Is the builder pattern used correctly in this program?

Comment: Its not a builder pattern, take a look at this http://www.javaworld.com/article/2074938/core-java/too-many-parameters-in-java-methods-part-3-builder-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Same construction process for different representation means that you are using the same method (and I don't mean a function wise) to build different variants of the same object (do not confuse with inheritance).

For example let say you have a Person class like that -

```
public class Person {
   private String name = "";
   private String surname = "";
   private String middleName = "";

   public Person(String name, String middleName, String surname) {
       this.name = name;
       this.middleName = middleName;
       this.surname = surname;
   }

   //.. a bunch of getters
}
```

When you construct a Person object you are bounded to provide all the parameters even though the object representation may change, for example a person with no middle name. The next best thing is to create a constructor that gets only first name and surname, which may solve the problem. But looking at it from that point of view whenever we realize that a parameter may exist or not we need to add a constructor. This growth is exponential 2^N where N is the number of parameters.

The [Builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) solves this issue.

Regarding your solution, you almost got it. Take a look at the example in the link above to find out what you are missing.